# Custom SQL filter in Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on an Azure function app that gets triggered when there is a new message in the dead-letter-queue of a topic's subscription. This FA is meant only to read the message from DLQ and not process it (not calling .Complete()). The issue here is that every time when there is a new message in DLQ, the FA gets triggered for all the previous messages as well. This makes the FA running continuously.

I was thinking of implementing a subscription filter wherein I can put a custom C# like logic.
Basically, I want to trigger the FA only if the message is new ie the message's sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc is no older than 30 sec from now.

Can anyone please suggest me the filter code for above logic ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you handle the dead-letter queue is incorrect. A message that is received from a queue and is not completed will be redelivered. That is the reason why you see the same messages replayed over and over again. You would need to either complete those messages or send them elsewhere, but not keep in the DLQ after they were read.

Regarding filtering, it's a feature only available for Subscriptions. It is not available for DLQs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a not well documented feature of Azure Service Bus which allows **automatic forwarding of deadlettered messages** to *another queue (or topic)* of your choice.

See here https://connectedcircuits.blog/2019/04/24/always-subscribe-to-dead-lettered-messages-in-an-azure-service-bus/ and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.forwarddeadletteredmessagesto?view=azure-dotnet. There was even an issue raised about the missing documentation ;-) https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25449

So would you could do in your scenario is to configure the "***ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo***" setting for your subscription and then perform the processing of the messages from the queue the deadlettered messages have been forwarded to.

If, for instance, you forward them to a topic so that you can then use a subscription with a filter based on the enqueue time property for your function. So you could have one subscription for your function that processes the message and completes it (removes it from it's queue) when done and another subscription for that topic in order to keep a remaining copy of all dead lettered messages (in case that is a requirement).